# Checking a SQL job status in C# using sp_help_job

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-agent-job

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423479/sql-job-result-in-c-sharp) gave the solution that in order to check the status of a job in C# you must run sp_help_job. The problem is when I try the query out in SQL, I'm getting an error from SQL Server saying "Could not find stored procedure 'sp_help_job'.

I tried running this SQL code in MSS 2008:

```
exec sp_help_job
```

Can someone post the exact query to find out the status of a job I just ran?

Comment: take a look at here http://anujyadavcse.blogspot.com/2010/06/check-sql-server-job-status-state-using.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are writing C# code, the easiest solution would probably be to use the SMO API to get the information you need. You can use the [Job class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.aspx) to get the current status and last result of a job.

Comment: if (job.LastRunOutcome == CompletionResult.Failed)
                    throw new Exception("'" + jobName + "' Failed");

Answer (score 6):

Change it to:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with running the EXEC command. However, changing the line to "exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job" worked.