# SQL Server 2008 Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I have many jobs which run at different scheduled time, I want to make a system which will tell me that Job A ran successfully and Job B failed etc.

Is there any API of SQL Server which can be used in Visual Studio C# to log the status of the jobs, or any suggestion how would I do that?

Comment: It depends on what kind of alert you need. Event log gives you status of the job. A small window service can read that event log and email you, or show on your desktop, or in some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you could create an sp or UDF by querying the sysjobhistory table...

Following links would give you some idea to fulfill your requirement,

[Get SQL Server Job Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404358/get-sql-server-job-status)

[Getting a Complete Job History](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Checking%20the%20status%20of%20SQL%20Server%20Agent%20jobs.aspx)

Hope this will help you